# Timeout procedure for using to much memory or cpu

Tags: linux, timeout

How hard is it to create some kind of timeout procedure for using to much memory or cpu on a linux/unix server? What would you have to do to do this?

This happens WAY to often. I understand you may need full resources if you are doing something with heavy resources. But when you leave something running for over 3 days that is ABSOLUTELY ridiculous. If you can't get what your doing done in like an hour then you should be on a personal server. Hundreds of people need to use that server and as you can tell from the screenshot it is an old server with limited resources. Can you think of a way to stop this after like an hour? In this case the person was using 99.9% of the server.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for a way to see what processes are consuming over X amount of CPU/MEM etc ?

Comment: Can you please explain further? Perhaps provide an example of what you want?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin I added more details.

Comment: @DarkHeart I added more details.

Comment: I don't know about software, but you could write a script. If you can't, I can make a simple one and post it as an answer for you.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin when you get a chance could you please? I'm not very good at writing scripts.

Comment: @rockstar797 Did the script work for you?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin haven't had a chance to test on anyone yet. No one is being cpu or memory hog right now :(.

Answer (score 0):

How's this? It may need some tweaking, but I'm sure you can figure that out with this as a starting point. You can run it from cron. If for some reason it doesn't work, it might be a formatting error due to the web site.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                               

# Internal field separator                                                                                                                                                                                
IFS="                                                                                                                                                                                                     
"                                                                                                                                                                                                         


# Settings
minUid=1000 # Minimum UID to kill (protect services and root)
maxCpu=25 # Maximum %CPU a process can consume for $maxTime
maxTime=3600 # Maxumum a time a process can run, in seconds

# Load and format process list
psList=$(ps -eo pid,uid,pcpu,etimes,args | awk '{ print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5}' | tail -n+2)

echo Please wait...

# Do this for each process
for process in $psList ; do {
        pid=$(echo $process | cut -d' ' -f1) #pid
        uid=$(echo $process | cut -d' ' -f2) #uid
        cpu=$(echo $process | cut -d' ' -f3) #cpu usage
        cpu=$(printf "%.0f" $cpu) #convert float to integer
        etimes=$(echo $process | cut -d' ' -f4) #elapsed time since pid was started
        cmd=$(echo $process | cut -d' ' -f5) #command name

        # Check if the UID is ok to kill
        if [ $pid -ge $minUid ]; then {

                # Check if it matches time + cpu usage restrictions
                if [ $etimes -ge $maxTime ] && [ $cpu -ge $maxCpu ] ; then {
                        # Indentified process to kill
                        echo "kill pid=$pid uid=$uid cpu=$cpu etimes=$etimes cmd=$cmd" 
                        kill -KILL $pid
                } fi
        } fi


} done
```